# Multiple render errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This has been asked many times but the one answer I found that I thought was the solution didn't help.  It pointed to this [article](https://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/) but maybe I'm not applying it right.

Here is the code situation:
Ok I am doing the following in my controller:

```
def create

   # some code
   create_record and return
end

private

  def create_record

      begin
          curr_user.events.build(#lots of fields).save!
      rescue
          render head :internal_server_error and return true
      end

      render head:ok and return true
  end
```

but I am getting the following error in my log: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError.  The offending lines noted following the error message are the call to create_record, the begin of the rescue block and the render in the rescue block.

Comment: Where's the error? You told us there was an error.

Comment: @Makoto updated answer

Comment: Keep just one render per action. Remove the create_record dependency, use just your create method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, when you `return` from the method `create_record`, it only returns from that method and **not** the actual action which called this method.

So, you `render head :internal_server_error` OR `render head: :ok` inside the method `create_record` and return from there. Control goes back to action `create` and by convention, it tries to render the template *create*. Hence, `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`.

To fix this, I would suggest change your code to following:

```
def create
  begin
    create_record
  rescue
    head :internal_server_error and return true
  end

  head :ok
end

private

def create_record
  curr_user.events.build(#lots of fields).save!
end
```

**Warning:** Check the syntax for `head :ok`. I am not sure of this..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The head statement inside the rescue block does not work three.  So, before the block I set `error = false`.  In the rescue section I set `error = true`.  Then after the block `if error head :internal_server_error else head :ok`